# where to put user defined magics for IPython

Tags: ipython

According to [the manual](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/config/custommagics.html#defining-magics), magics is just normal functions or member functions of derived class of `IPython.core.magic.Magics` and should be registered using

```
get_ipython().register_magics(MyMagics)
```

My questions:

1. where should I put those class/function definitions? Should I add their path to `$PYTHONPATH`?
2. where is the standard place to register them?
3. is there a folder to hold all user-defined magics and is automatically loaded when IPython is launched?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please completly read the page you are linking to, in particular at the top, is written in red:

> This documentation is for an old version of IPython. You can find docs for newer versions [here].

By following this link you can find the new documentation, in particular [this page](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config/custommagics.html).

On this page you will find things like:

> Below we show code you can place in a file that you load from your configuration, such as any file in the startup subdirectory of your default IPython profile.

And

> Here is a full example of a magic package. You can distribute magics using setuptools, distutils, or any other distribution tools like flit for pure Python packages.

To summarize:

Magics can be defined anywhere as long as they can be imported.

Usually author defined magics in packages that define the `load_ipython_extension` function, making them loadable with `%load_ext`, and the `load_ipython_extension` register the magic.

You can load extension by default using the configuration file and the `c.InteractiveShellApp.extensions` option.